# Joomla modules to only displayed to specific usersgroup

Tags: joomla, module, restriction

I need to able to restrict menu modules to their user group. I have two user group called "contractor and supplier" I have separate menu module for each and only be seen if they are they user group.

But when I login for either I can see the other user menu, visit http://new.oljanafm.com.au And login as a supplier on both login forms:

username: telstra
pw: 1234

How do I make it so each menu can only be seen when they login.

Thanks,
Nep

Comment: Please take a look at this: http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/style-a-design/modules-management/10307

Answer (score 1):

Menu's are displayed by modules, simply set the menu to the group you want.

In the `module` that displays the menu set the `Access` menu to the "Contractor" or "Supplier" group as required.

e.g. in the Joomla 3 Manager you can see the Modules button on the right end of each Menu row.

[image: Joomla 3 Menu Manger]

If you click on the Modules button you will be shown a summary of where it's displayed (template position) and the viewing access group that can see it, as shown below:

[image: Joomla 3 Module button in Menu Manager]

If you click on the module entry you can edit the module directly and set the access, like this:
[image: Access item for a menu module in Joomla 3]

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

In your module , you can create `User Groups` as a `Module Params`.
So using this option once the module is installed for one menu item choose required user groups. Then for the second menu item create New module from `Module manager ->Tool bar menu`.
choose the other user groups from module param.
Assign each module correctly with menu's. Simply Done!

You can create usergroups in module param using the following code in your module XML

```
<field name="guest_usergroup" type="usergroup"
        label="COM_USERS_CONFIG_FIELD_GUEST_USER_GROUP_LABEL"
        description="COM_USERS_CONFIG_FIELD_GUEST_USER_GROUP_DESC" 
        multiple="true" />
```

For [more](http://docs.joomla.org/Usergroup_form_field_type) about usergroups, and more about [module params](http://docs.joomla.org/Standard_form_field_and_parameter_types).

Hope it make sense..

Comment: Thanks Jobin, bit confusing haha. I have installed Ad. Module Manager which gives the exclude user group :)

Comment: @behind the seen , this is the logic :) Once you set this param from back end you can check it value on front module. Using plugin will be easy and fast result.(Just understand the idea!)

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to use a 3rd party solution called [Metamodpro](http://metamodpro.com/)

Once you install that, here are some recipes that you could use:

> if (MM_USER_REGISTERED ) return 46; //a plain registered user, no additional privileges
>
> if ( MM_USER_AUTHOR ) return 47; //show a notice for "Author" users
>
> if ( MM_USER_EDITOR ) return 48; //show a notice for "Editor" users
>
> if ( MM_LOGGED_IN && MM_NOT_USER_AUTHOR ) return 53; //show a notice to anyone logged in who is not in the "Author" group
>
> if ( $user->usertype == "My Special Group Name" ) return 54; //if you are using any Joomla extensions that allow you to create your own user groups